# Set a local variable and use throughout the query batch?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

Once I insert default values in the table I store the result of scope identity in a variable

```
insert into OrderPlaced default values;
declare @id bigint;
set @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

After this, I have to run some other pieces of code that change the value of scope identity and after running those pieces of code I have to use the value of @id again but it shows an error saying that I must declare the variable which I have already done above.

```
EXEC dbo.GetRecieptById @ID = @id;
```

Unfortunately, I can't just select the whole code block and execute it at once as this is for a presentation and I have to show each individual steps.

Comment: Its not clear how you are running your code. You should give further examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is how to persist the variable across batches - not within a batch.

One way would be to use [`SESSION_CONTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
declare @id bigint;
insert into OrderPlaced default values;
set @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
EXEC sys.sp_set_session_context  @key= N'@id',@value = @id 

GO

declare @id bigint = CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'@id') AS BIGINT)
EXEC dbo.GetRecieptById @ID = @id;
```

Comment: i tried this, but sys.sp_set_session_context is not a stored procedure in my sql server

Comment: Ah, needs SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and later

Comment: that would explain it, the version provided to us was older than 2016

Comment: @HSaad the `SESSION_CONTEXT` is valid for a specific process so you can use it in the current session. [SESSION_CONTEXT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @M.Mohabbati - they can't use it at all as seems they are on SQL Server 2014 or something even older

Comment: You can use `SET CONTEXT_INFO`

Comment: @Charlieface - yeah considerably more painful though as it is a single binary value so the code to extract values from it would not win any beauty contests (assuming OP needs more than one value persisted)

Answer (score 1):

What you wanna do ?

If you want to access the latest data in your Order Table, you can access the latest data with this code.

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM OrderPlaced
```

Answer (score 1):

The local variable can not be used in a separate execution. You have to store all values in a **temporary table**.

These tables are stored in `tempdb`. Use **local temporary table** with one **#** or **global temporary table** with two **##** at the beginning of the table name as follow:

```
create table #local_temp_table
(Id bigint not null);

...

insert into #local_temp_table ...

...

select Id from #local_temp_table;
```

OR

```
create table ##global_temp_table
(Id bigint not null);

...

insert into ##global_temp_table ...

...

select Id from ##global_temp_table;
```

They are **automatically dropped** when they go out of scope, however, you can drop them manually.

Take a look at the following link:

[Temporary Tables in SQL Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/)